# Add-Content for each line in a CSV using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, csv

I'm creating a simple script to pull a chrome extension from a user's file path, search the chrome app store for the name of the extension, and enter it into the csv:

```
# Open file
$file = Import-Csv 'filepath'

# Loop through each line of CSV
foreach ($line in $file)
{       
    # Assign file path, and regex just the extension
    $path = $line.path
    $extension = $path -replace '.*\\Extensions\\'

    # Open chrome webstore for specific extension
    $result = Invoke-webrequest -Uri "https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/$extension" -Method Get
    $resultTable = @{}  
    
    # Grab title of extension and place in CSV
    $title = $result.ParsedHtml.title
    Add-Content -Path 'filepath' -Value "$path,$extension,$title"
    
    # Create table and return as an object
    $resultTable.$extension = $title
    Write-Output $resultTable
}
```

Doing this works fine, but appends the results to the bottom of the table instead of in it's neighbouring column, as shown:
[image]

How would I go about simply placing the output into the fields beside, instead of adding to the bottom?

Any help would be much appreciated, and thank you in advance.

EDIT: To make things a little clearer.
The file originally looks like this:

[image]

My desired output would be to have the extension, and title in the same row, but neighbouring columns, as such:

[image]

Comment: Slightly different, but thank you. I've added an edit to the original post to clarify what I'm asking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using `Import-Csv` to read your file, which I assume is a proper CSV, you can use `Export-Csv` to output custom objects.

```
# Open file
$file = Import-Csv 'filepath'

# Loop through each line of CSV
# store results in $resultTable
$resultTable = foreach ($line in $file)
{       
    # Assign file path, and regex just the extension
    $path = $line.path
    $extension = $path -replace '.*\\Extensions\\'

    # Open chrome webstore for specific extension
    $result = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/$extension" -Method Get
    
    # Grab title of extension and place in CSV
    $title = $result.ParsedHtml.title
    
    # Create and output custom object with path,extension,title properties
    [pscustomobject]@{
        Path = $path
        Extension = $extension
        Title = $title
    }
}
# Export to CSV overwriting 'filepath'
$resultTable | Export-Csv 'filepath' -NoType
```

`Export-Csv` converts an input object into a CSV. Each property of the object becomes a column and each property value is output under those respective columns. Each object becomes its own row in the case of an array of objects.

Comment: That worked perfectly, thank you. I'll have to read up more on custom objects because that seems super useful.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of writing the file directly, you can construct each row with `[PSCustomObject]`'s and then export with `Export-Csv`

```
Import-Csv 'filepath' | ForEach-Object {
    $extension = $_.path -replace '.*\\Extensions\\'
    $result = Invoke-webrequest -Uri "https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/$extension" -Method Get
    $title = $result.ParsedHtml.title
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Path      = $_.path
        Extension = $extension
        Title     = $title
    }
} | Export-Csv 'filepath' -NoTypeInformation
```

You could also do it all with calculated properties.

```
$SelectProps = @(
    "Path",
    @{n="Extension";e={$_.path -replace '.*\\Extensions\\'}},
    @{n="Title";e={(Invoke-webrequest -Uri "https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/$($_.path -replace '.*\\Extensions\\')" -Method Get).ParsedHtml.title}}
)

Import-Csv 'filepath' |
    Select-Object $SelectProps |
        Export-Csv 'filepath' -NoTypeInformation
```